# When updating heading and other content image in the database becomes empty

Tags: php

```
require('connection.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {

  $_FILES["image"]["name"];
  $imagename = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
  move_uploaded_file($imagename ,"uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);    
  $image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $name1=$_POST['name'];
  $description=$_POST['description'];

  } else {

  $image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $name1=$_POST['name'];
  $description=$_POST['description'];
  }

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `service` SET `name` ='$name1' ,`description` ='$description',`image`='".$image."'  WHERE `service_id`= '". $_SESSION["id"]."' ");

}

if($sql>0)
{
  echo "<script>alert('Successfully Entered!!!'); 
  window.location='service_view.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

Context:
This is code is for updating the contents in database(heading,description and image).The code is working when all fields are selected.Editing is done by modalbox edit.The code is working when the feilds are separatly selected.For example if i select all the three fields code is working correctly and every contents are updated.But when i select the heading field only to update the image stored in the database becomes empty.

Comment: So you need to check what fields are empty and not update them.

Comment: Can other details update to database ?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. That will make it easier for both us and you to read the flow and find potential errors.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: All fields are updating.But if update heading or description ,the image in database becomes empty. I want to keep that image same when updating other details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create separate query on each condition :

```
...
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{   
    if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"]))
    {
        $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $imagename = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        move_uploaded_file($imagename ,"uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);  
        $image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $name1=$_POST['name'];
        $description=$_POST['description'];
        $sql=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `service` SET `name` ='$name1' ,`description` ='$description',`image`='".$image."'  WHERE `service_id`= '". $_SESSION["id"]."' ");
    }
    else
    {
        $name1=$_POST['name'];
        $description=$_POST['description'];
        $sql=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `service` SET `name` ='$name1' ,`description` ='$description'  WHERE `service_id`= '". $_SESSION["id"]."' ");
    }
}
...
```